# Sharepoint - Retrieving user group and permission rights programmatically

Tags: c#, sharepoint

currently I'm trying to retrieve all the groups that is in my sharepoint site. After which, I need to know which users are in the group and the level of site permission for each user. I'm using WSS 3.0 , developing in C# (visual studio 2008). 
Help really needed as I'm still new in this area. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Groups can be found like:

```
SPSite siteCollection = new SPSite("site url");
SPWeb site = siteCollection.OpenWeb();

foreach(SPGroup group in site.Groups){
  Console.WriteLine(group.Name);

   foreach(SPUser u in group.Users){
         //will give you users in group, you can then grab the roles of the user
   }
}
```

To find what permissions a role has:

```
SPSite oSiteCollection = SPContext.Current.Site;
using(SPWeb oWebsite = oSiteCollection.AllWebs["Site_Name"])
{
    SPMember oMember = oWebsite.Roles["Role_Name"];
    oWebsite.Permissions[oMember].PermissionMask = 
        SPRights.ManageLists | SPRights.ManageListPermissions;
}
```

The permissions matrix can be found [here](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepointtechnology/HA101001491033.aspx)

Comment: thanks for the reply but i hit error for 
listGroup += (groupCol.Name);
                 
'Microsoft.SharePoint.SPGroupCollection' does not contain a definition for 'Name' and no extension method 'Name' accepting a first argument of type 'Microsoft.SharePoint.SPGroupCollection' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

foreach(SPUser singleUser in group.Users)
The name 'group' does not exist in the current context 

Pls advice, thanks!

Comment: It looks like your variable groupCol is of type SPGroupCollection, which doesn't have a Name property (the items in this collection however do). The code I provided doesn't do anything like that. You should post your code so we can see what you are doing wrong.

Comment: Do you want me to paste it here?

 SPGroupCollection groupCol = oWebsite.Groups;
                    foreach (SPGroup Group in oWebsite.Groups)
                    {
                        //ListGroup.Text += (Group.Name) + "<BR>";
                        Label1.Text += (Group.Name) + "<BR>";
                    }
output is :
Team Site Members
Team Site Owners
Team Site Visitors

any idea why? Thanks

Comment: Team Site Members
Team Site Owners
Team Site Visitors

is the outcome instead of the groups in my sharepoint site. Any idea why? Please guide. Thanks

Comment: This answer won't work outside of sharepoint, e.g. WinForms/Console because you can't get context on the current site.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for code to work for using client object model, you may review the following links.

1. For getting the groups.
   http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/24075.how-to-get-sharepoint-user-group-names-in-a-netc-client-application-using-sharepoint-client-object-model.aspx
2. For getting the permission levels associated with groups.
   http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/24087.how-to-get-the-permission-levels-associated-with-sharepoint-user-groups-using-client-object-model-in-netc.aspx

Comment: Kindly add the relevant part of the link in your answer, so that it ensures that the solution would be available even if the links are down.